# Cannot access RDS (public mysql) from EC2 on another Aws Account

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, rds

I have a public RDS mysql that I can access locally from my pc.  When I try to login to an EC2 on a different account than the RDS, I cannot access it using mysql client or utilities.  The EC2 has an elastic IP and the IP is in the RDS security group port 3306.  Strange that I can access it from my local pc but not from another Aws account EC2 instance.

btw, I did try to find answers to this before posting but couldnt find anything.

Comment: Have you tried the internal IP instead of the external IP of the connecting instance?

Comment: @ceejayoz - The Ec2 wouldn't know about the RDS's internal ip...its in a different Aws acount, Vpc, etc

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out.  I had to add a new route for the RDS's VPC and set the route target to the gateway.